# Staf with python interpreter is strucking in middle and asking for keyboard interrupt

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using STAF for queuing messages between processes. and I wrote the code in python, it also have threads to serve each request from server process.

When I run the processes, they are struck (pausing, and resumes when given a keyboard interrupt) in the middle of execution.

Is it the problem of the Python interpreter.. because when I run the code in PyScripter IDE debug mode there was no such issue.

Thank you for the replies in advance.